# Best practice to setup env variables with ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm just starting with Ansible, so to be more specific i wanted to setup several zookeeper vagrant machines and for this i've made a separate role - *zookeeper*. Install task was easy, but what's the best was to configure env vars in general? In my use case i've added two vars into vars/main.yml:

```
---
env:
  ZOOKEEPER_INSTALL: "/usr/share/zookeeper"
  PATH: "$PATH:$ZOOKEEPER_INSTALL/bin"
```

Then added this to the role task:

```
- name: Export ZooKeeper env vars
  shell: export env
```

But i didn't find this vars in `printenv`. Then i've tried to change `shell` module with `environment`, but it seems to do another kind of stuff. So what's the proper way to set env vars, so that they would work even after `server reboot`/`vagrant halt`?

Comment: I use `/etc/profile.d` as Strahinja suggests, and it works great for me. Google "ansible zookeeper" for tons of different playbooks and roles on github.  [Here's one](https://github.com/AnsibleShipyard/ansible-zookeeper).  The examples should help you pick up which ansible modules/task-types to use where (and that you *rarely* need to use `shell`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to set system environment variables, you have to do that the same way you would do it without Ansible, e.g. by dropping the appropriate code into `/etc/profile.d`. You could probably use a `template` module for this and include all the variables you need in it.